# I am getting Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Not sure what to do, can't connect when i run >>node index.js in git shell. it gives me the following

LoL RPG started on port 8080
connection error: [Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]]

```
/* ==== MONGODB ==== */
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var db          = require('./config/db.js');

mongoose.connect(db.url);
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() { console.log("Mongo DB connected!"); });

 /* ==== config/db.js ==== */
module.exports = "mongodb://<username>:<username>@ds052837.mongolab.com:52837/lolrpg";
```

Comment: Simply based on the error, it's trying to connect to a mongoDB url set to `undefined`. 27017 is the default mongoDB port. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/ But posting literally ANY code would help a lot.

Comment: @Tony do these codes help?

Comment: I assume you did not start MongoDB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that your `db` variable in the first section of code is referring to the connection string, but you try to access a `url` property on it, which ends up being undefined.

Replace `mongoose.connect(db.url)` with `mongoose.connect(db)`.

Alternatively, in db.js, you can replace `module.exports = ...` with `module.exports.url = ...`.

Comment: Thanks! i can't believe I missed that!